# Populating cells within a 2d list in python

Tags: python

Exact wording from assignment:
We pass in 2 numbers, A and B. You should create a list with A rows and B columns.
You should then populate each cell like this …
'R0C0’, 'R0C1’, ‘R0C2’ etc.
I was able to create the list with all 0's but not able to modify to correct output.

Was given this but don't know how to implement.

```
for row in rows:  # Each row
  for col in cols:  # The columns on the current row
      print('This is row: %s and col: %s' % (row,col)


    A= int(sys.argv[1])
    B= int(sys.argv[2])

    # Your code goes here
    a = [([0]*B) for row in range(0 , A)]

    print(a)
```

Expected Output: [['R0C0', 'R0C1', 'R0C2'], ['R1C0', 'R1C1', 'R1C2']]
Your Program Output: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

Comment: I find your question confusing. Can you rephrase it in as simple English as possible?

Comment: How do you think your code will produce the expected output?

Comment: Your code create lists of integers. You need to edit it to add strings with the proper index. Also seems that there is some code not properly formatted, please edit your question so that is more clear.

Comment: My code was just one I used to see if I could generate a list of rows and columns based off the input.

Comment: Given A (number of rows) and B number of columns how do I output a 2d list with the desired result.

Comment: Here is the exact wording from assignment:                                                    We pass in 2 numbers, A and B.                                                                     You should create a list with A rows and B columns.
You should then populate each cell like this …
'R0C0’, 'R0C1’, ‘R0C2’ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using either `A` nor `B` in your result, you're using `0`, that's why you're getting `[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]`.

You can fix that by using string formatting to get the row and column you want.

```
num_rows = int(sys.argv[1])
num_columns = int(sys.argv[2])

result = [["R{row}C{col}".format(row=row, col=col) for col in range(num_columns)] for row in range(num_rows)]
```

Or, more succinctly (with f-strings in Py3.6+):

```
result = [[f"R{row}C{col}" for col in range(num_columns)] for row in range(num_rows)]
```

You could also initialize your list, then iterate through and set each value, but I'm not sure what you gain from doing this in this example.

```
import itertools

def make_2d_list(self, rows, columns):
    """Makes a 2D list with None for each value."""

    return [[None for _ in range(columns)] for _ in range(rows)]

base_list = make_2d_list(num_rows, num_columns)

for row, col in itertools.product(range(num_rows), range(num_columns))
    # itertools.product is a concise form of nested for loops.
    # These two expressions are equivalent:
    #
    # for a, b, c, d, e in itertools.product(as, bs, cs, ds, es):
    #     ...
    #
    # for a in as:
    #     for b in bs:
    #         for c in cs:
    #             for d in ds:
    #                 for e in es:
    #                     ...
    base_list[row][col] = f"R{row}C{col}"
```